# SonarQube4.0 : Issue Page not opening

Tags: sonarqube

When I click on the issue tab in **SonarQube dashboard**, I get the error:

> We're sorry, but something went wrong.
>   Please try back in a few minutes and contact support if the problem persists.
>   Go back to the homepage

I use `JDK 1.7`

**Sonar.logs** file gives the following error stack-->

```
2014.08.26 13:43:06 ERROR o.s.s.ui.JRubyFacade  Fail to render: http://    10.180.5.10:9000/issues/search
undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
    On line #70 of app/views/issues/_list.html.erb

67: <%= h @issues_result.user(issue.assignee).name if issue.assignee -%>
68: </td>
69: <td>
70: <%= h @issues_result.actionPlan(issue).name if issue.actionPlanKey() -%>
71: </td>
72: <td width="1%" nowrap>
73: <%= human_short_date(Api::Utils.java_to_ruby_datetime(issue.updateDate())) -%>

app/views/issues/_list.html.erb:70
file:lib/jruby-complete-1.7.6.jar!/jruby/java/java_ext/java.util.rb:7:in `each'
app/views/issues/_list.html.erb:37
org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2225:in `send'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/renderable.rb:34:in `render'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/base.rb:306:in `with_template'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/renderable.rb:30:in `render'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/renderable_partial.rb:20:in `render'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:30:in `benchmark'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/renderable_partial.rb:19:in `render'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/template.rb:205:in `render_template'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/renderable_partial.rb:44:in `render_partial'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/partials.rb:184:in `render_partial'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/base.rb:267:in `render'
app/views/issues/_search.html.erb:3
org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2225:in `send'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/renderable.rb:34:in `render'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/base.rb:306:in `with_template'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/renderable.rb:30:in `render'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/renderable_partial.rb:20:in `render'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:30:in `benchmark'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/renderable_partial.rb:19:in `render'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/template.rb:205:in `render_template'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/renderable_partial.rb:44:in `render_partial'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/partials.rb:184:in `render_partial'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/base.rb:267:in `render'
app/views/issues/search.html.erb:7
org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2225:in `send'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/renderable.rb:34:in `render'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/base.rb:306:in `with_template'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/renderable.rb:30:in `render'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/template.rb:205:in `render_template'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/base.rb:265:in `render'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/base.rb:348:in `_render_with_layout'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/base.rb:262:in `render'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/base.rb:1252:in `render_for_file'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/base.rb:936:in `render'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:51:in `render_with_benchmark'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:51:in `render_with_benchmark'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/base.rb:1328:in `default_render'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/base.rb:1334:in `perform_action'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:617:in `call_filters'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:610:in `perform_action_with_filters'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:68:in `perform_action_with_benchmark'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:68:in `perform_action_with_benchmark'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/rescue.rb:160:in `perform_action_with_rescue'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/flash.rb:151:in `perform_action_with_flash'
org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2221:in `send'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/base.rb:532:in `process'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:606:in `process_with_filters'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/base.rb:391:in `process'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/base.rb:386:in `call'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/routing/route_set.rb:438:in `call'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:87:in `dispatch'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:121:in `_call'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:130:in `build_middleware_stack'
org/jruby/RubyProc.java:290:in `call'
org/jruby/RubyProc.java:224:in `call'
gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:29:in `call'
gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:34:in `cache'
gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:9:in `cache'
gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:28:in `call'
gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:361:in `call'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/string_coercion.rb:25:in `call'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/params_parser.rb:15:in `call'
file:lib/jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar!/jruby/rack/session_store.rb:70:in `context'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/failsafe.rb:26:in `call'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:106:in `call'
file:lib/jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar!/rack/adapter/rails.rb:34:in `serve_rails'
file:lib/jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar!/rack/adapter/rails.rb:39:in `call'
file:lib/jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar!/rack/handler/servlet.rb:22:in `call'
```

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution.
Issue was resolved in this http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-4449  but, somehow it did not get translated to the SonarQube 4.0 version i downloaded and was using.

The patch was to delete the rows in the issues table which still have the deleted action plans linked to them -->

Update issues set action_plan_key=NULL where action_plan_key is not null AND not exists (select * from action_plans ap where ap.kee = action_plan_key)

One can check whether any such row is there or not -->

select * from issues i
left outer join action_plans ap on i.action_plan_key = ap.kee
where i.action_plan_key is not null and ap.kee is null;